# Access an object method with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a symfony controller returning this:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('menu' => $menu));
```

`menu` is a `Menu` object.

In my template I want to call a method from the Menu class:

```
getHTML(string s1, String s2, array tab)
```

returning a HTML string.

How do I do that in the template? Is it even possible ?

Comment: Although this is a proper answer, it is a bad practice to implement getHtml() inside php classes. Objects should only contain data, and template / html rendering should be done inside twig. You can look in macros or something like that.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yea, it's possible:

```
{{ menu.getHTML('first-string', 'second-string', ['tab1', 'tab2']) }}
```

Since Twig handles getters and issers automatically, you can omit the `get` part:

```
{{ menu.HTML(...) }}
```