# Twig Type Reflection in Symfony 2

Tags: php, reflection, twig, symfony-2.3

I'm working in a generic *index.html.twig* template, for testing purposes. So, I want to check the objects properties arriving to the view. I'm testing a lister for any entity in my database.

I'll loop an object's keys obtained. But the function: **keys**, from Twig official book, only works with with arrays or collections. 
Exists any solution to this?

Here goes the code:

```
{% if model and model.data %}
 {% set firstKeys= model.data|first %}     
    {% for key, item in firstKeys %}
        {{ attribute(item, key) }}<br>   
    {% endfor %}
    <p>
         ...
    </p>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277736/access-an-object-method-with-twig

Comment: In that case, I would need any php function for doing the Type reflection and passing from the Controller the properties array. In my case, the object Employee, has several properties (not methods) that I would like to know in the template. Do you know such php function?